# Make a Form Oledb Connection available as a design time property of a User Control

Tags: vb.net, forms

I have a set of User Controls in a separate project in a vb.net solution.  One User Control type needs access to the Form's data connection.  The Form is in a project that has a reference to the User Control project.  I am able to create instances of that User Control on the form.  I would like the User Control instance on the form, at design time, to be able to set its Connection property to a public Connection field or property that has been set in the form.  In the properties window of UserControl1 on the form, only "(none)" shows as available for the Connection property.  I have tried setting an attribute on the User Control Connection property -- System.ComponentModel.Browsable(True).  That did not make the form Connection available.  Is there a way to make the form's Connection (and other object properties) available in the User Control's properties window?  I am using vb.net 3.5.

Comment: Why does it have to be a design time prop?  The form could set the UC connection property to its own in initialization code.  This is a bad idea by the way - Connections are not meant to be shared or resused

Comment: I would like the User Control to be able to manage data in a database independent of the form, except that the form provides the connection.  The code for adding, updating, etc is in the User Control because the tables accessed by the UserControl are simple and have identical column types, so the coding only varies by column names and the values of each record.  Is there an attribute that makes a connection property in the form visible in the properties window of the User Control?

Comment: Have the user control create its own connection - problem solved.  See [Connection Pooling](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms254502(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: I can set the connection string as a property in the UCs and create the connection as needed.  Thank you for your input.